# Magento - 1 x SKU covering multiple SKU's - How to?

Tags: magento-1.7, products-management, bundled-product, grouped-products, sku

I'm struggling a bit on how to sell a product that is sold individually, but also in a package including more products. Let me illustrate it as a real example:

Sample pack e-liquid (including 1x orange, 1x strawberry, 1x apple)

Customer can choose: strength: 0, 6, 12, 18, 24 (meaning that each flavor has 5 SKU's)

I can't figure out how to make this right - the problem is that the inventory should adjust itself accordingly whether the customer buys a product alone or in combination with other products (as in the case illustrated above - the Sample Pack)

Lets say we sell Orange with SKU: N1 individually it will automatically reduce the stock-level - no problem. BUT this should also happen when the same product is sold in a Sample pack. How can this be done right?

Hope anyone can help! I really tried to study several tutorials, but can't find any example helping me solve this problem.

If my explanation is not clear enough, please fire me additional questions. Thanks!

PS. If you want to see a real example, please check this link: http://din-ecigaret.dk/lille-rygestopspakke

This is a starterkit including including 3 different liquids (that customer can choose) The strength is predefined (16mg) as we at this given time, we can not mess up our inventory control by letting customers chose between several strengths - but it would be very convenient if for the customer if this could be possible. Again, that refers back to the question I'm asking - how can we do this right without messing up our inventory completely?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using bundle and configurable products.

Create configurable product for your first flavor:

1. create "orange" configurable product with "strength" attribute as configurable attribute
2. create children products for each strength (0, 6, 12, 18, 24) using "Quick Create" form

Then repeat this for each of your flavors.

Finally create "sample pack" bundle product and create "orange" as first bundle product option. Add all "orange" configurable product children (strengths) as its selections. You need to specifically add all children as Magento doesn't support adding configurable product as direct children of bundle product. Then repeat this for all products you want include in sample pack.

Now when customer buys bundle or configurable product, stock for children should be reduced.